# Implicit integral equation involving square root

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, implicit-function

I have the following integral equation stemming from a physical problem (connected with BCS theory):
$$
1 = \frac{2}{\pi}u \int_0^1 dx \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{u^2\phi^2 + x^2}},
$$
where $u$ is a positive parameter and I have to solve the equation for the variable $\phi$, which is acceptable only within the range $-1/2 < \phi < 1/2$.
I guess that asking for an analytic expression $\phi(u)$ is probably too much, but at least I would like an approximated solution when $u\ll 1$.
From physical considerations and numerical analysis I know that the solution should be something like $\phi \sim e^{-1/u}$, however I have no clue about how to prove it.
Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I am not able to transform this integral into elliptic functions, and Wolfram Mathematica can't solve it either. Moreover, I am not sure how to expand for small values of $u$... I am thinking that there's no way out, except numerics.

Comment: *Mathematica* can do it if you include more conditions. This should work in v.13.1+:
`Integrate[Sqrt[1 - x^2] / Sqrt[u^2 f^2 + x^2], x, Assumptions -> u < 1 && -1/2 < f < 1/2]`

Comment: ... and you can manually evaluate the result at $0$ and $1$ (I ran a definite `Integrate` input but it never completed for me). It's given in terms of an *incomplete* elliptic integral (second kind). OTOH, if I'm not mistaken, differentiating both sides w.r.t. $\phi$, then computing the integral gives a somewhat simpler result in terms of two *complete* EIs (first and second), and since the right side vanishes one ends up with having to solve$$E\left(\frac i{u\phi}\right) = K\left(\frac i{u\phi}\right)$$(using Wikipedia's convention for the elliptic modulus, not the WL's). But what now?

Comment: what is this notation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $a>0$ and $x>0$, using the elliptic integral of the second kind
$$I=\int \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{a^2+x^2}}\,dx=-i E\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)|-a^2\right)$$
$$J=\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{a^2+x^2}}\,dx=-i E\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)|-a^2\right)$$ So, with $a=u\phi$, the equation to be solved for $\phi$ is
$$1+\frac{2 i }{\pi }\, u\, E\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{u \phi
   }\right)|-u^2 \phi ^2\right) =0$$

This equation cannot be inversed but any numerical method (such as Newton) should work as a charm $\cdots$ provided a reasonable estimate.

I had no problem using $\phi_0=e^{-1/u}$

But, as usual, @Svyatoslav's estimate
$$\phi_0=\frac 4 u  \exp\left( -\left(\frac{\pi }{2 u}+1\right)\right)$$ is extremely good.

**Edit**

Doing what @user170231 suggested in comments (sorry fot not having paid a sufficient attention), we have somthing simpler (even if there is one hypergeometric function). But, it can be simplified as
$$J=\frac{\left(a^2+1\right) }{a}K\left(-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)-a   E\left(-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$

The equation is then
$$1-\frac{2 \left(u^2 \phi ^2+1\right) K\left(-\frac{1}{u^2 \phi
   ^2}\right)}{\pi  \phi }+\frac{2 u^2 \phi  E\left(-\frac{1}{u^2   \phi ^2}\right)}{\pi }=0$$ which can be expanded as a series

$$1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n\, u^{2n+1}=0$$ where
$$A_0=-\frac{2 \left(\log \left(\frac{u}{4}\right)+\log (\phi)+1\right)}{\pi }$$
$$A_1=\frac{\phi ^2 \left(\log \left(\frac{u}{4}\right)+\log (\phi)\right)}{2 \pi }$$

$A_0$ is the term given by @Svyatoslav.

I suppose that we are not very far from a solution in terms of the generalized Lambert function.

Using $$\phi_0=\frac 4 u  \exp\left( -\left(\frac{\pi }{2 u}+1\right)\right)$$ use Newton method
$$\phi_{n+1}=\phi_n-\frac {f(\phi_n)}{f'(\phi_n)}$$ with
$$f'(\phi)=\frac{2 u^2 }{\pi }\left(E\left(-\frac{1}{u^2 \phi
   ^2}\right)-K\left(-\frac{1}{u^2 \phi ^2}\right)\right)$$

**Update**

Let $\phi=\frac{1}{u \sqrt{x}}$ and we look for the inverse of
$$\frac 2 \pi u=\frac{  \sqrt{x}}{ (x+1) K(-x)- E(-x)}\tag 1$$ where the rhs is a nice function (its reciprocal looks like a Lambert function).

Expand for large $x$ to $O\left(\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\right)$ and let $x=e^t$ to obtain
$$e^{-t}=4\, \frac {t+2 (2 \log (2)-1) }{t+ \left(\frac{u}{\pi }+4 \log (2)\right) }$$

and the solution is given in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

Expanding the rhs of $(1)$ as a series, we have  avery good asymptotics
$$\frac 2 \pi u=\frac 1 t \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}\, {P_n(t)}\,\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^n \quad \text{where} \quad x=\frac{1}{16} e^{2( t+1)}$$ the first polynomials being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(t) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & \frac{t+1}{4} \\
 2 & \frac{14 t^2+17 t+8}{128} \\
 3 & \frac{90 t^3+113 t^2+78 t+24}{1536} \\
 4 & \frac{6948 t^4+8551 t^3+6860 t^2+3360 t+768}{196608} \\
 5 & \frac{90900 t^5+107183 t^4+91810 t^3+55380 t^2+21120
   t+3840}{3932160}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This is beautiful! I could not imagine that I could go this far, thanks! However, if I expand this with Mathematica, I get a slightly different equation w.r.t @Svyatoslav's estimate, but I don't see why (unless Mathematica is giving me wrong results for some reasons)

Comment: @Matteo. Could you show the syntax you used ? In any manner, I always try to get first the antiderivative.

Comment: Sure (I replace $\phi$ with f)!  Assuming[{u > 0, 0 < f < 1/2}, FullSimplify[(2/Pi)*Series[-I*u*EllipticE[I*ArcSinh[1/(u*f)], -(u*f)^2], {u, 0, 1}]]]

Comment: The output is $(2u/\pi)[\log{2}- \log{(u\phi)}]$

Answer (score 3):

*Too long for a comment*

Denoting $a=|u\phi|$ and considering the case $a\ll1$
$$I(a)=\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{a^2 + x^2}}dx\overset{IBP}{=}\ln(x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2})\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\bigg|_0^1+\int_0^1\frac {\ln(x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2})xdx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
The remaining integral is regular at $a=0$; therefore
$$I(a)=-\ln a+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(2x)\,x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx+o(a)=-\ln a+2\ln2-1+o(a)$$
and your equation becomes
$$\boxed{\,\,1=\frac2\pi u\big(-\ln|u\phi|+2\ln2-1+o(|u\phi|));\,\,|u\phi|\ll1\,\,}$$
You should exclude the case of $\phi=0$ from consideration: in this case the integral diverges at any $u$.

Comment: Wow! Beautiful solution, thanks a lot. There's one detail I still don't get: if I take @Claude Leibovici 's solution and blindly expand it with Mathematica for $a \to 0$,  I get the equation $1=(2u/\pi) [\log{2} - \log{(u\phi)}]$, which is slightly different. How is that possible?

Comment: I checked numerically the initial integral: the asymptotics of $I(a)$ is correct. Moreover, the integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(2x)\,x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ appears directly (in one line) and is equal $2\ln2-1$ (I checked with WolframAlpha). I'm not good at special functions, so I cannot explain why there is a difference in the answers. One of the explanation could be that the function $e^{-1/u}$ is not analytical at $u\to0$, and we have to know how Mathematica treat it in this limit...

Comment: Numeric check with WolframAlpha for $a=0.1:\,\, I(0.1)=2.698...$, approximation $=-\ln(0.1)+2\ln2-1=2.689$    ( https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_0%5E1++%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7B0.01+%2B+x%5E2%7D%7Ddx  and    https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%5Cln%280.1%29%2B2%5Cln2-1)

Comment: There is one point : when $u$ is small, $\phi$ is much smaller. Is there a way to take into account ? As I wrote, I have the strange feeling that we are not very far from a solution in terms of the generalized Lambert function. Do you agree ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: I found Lambert function (once more)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, you are right about $\phi$. The asymptotics ($I(a)$) is also correct. I don't think there the is reason to evaluate higher terms ($o|u\phi|$). In fact, even correction $2\ln2-1$ does not work at $u\ll1$ - only one term is needed in fact. BTW, superconductivity was explained so late because of this non-analytic behavior: people struggled to apply the perturbation theory, which is not applicable for such function...

Comment: Glad to see that, once more, we fully agree.